Insied bitbucket pipeline ERROR: NodejsNpmBuilder:Resolver - Path resolution for runtime: nodejs20.x of binary: npm was not successful
I am trying to deploy to AWS using bitbucket pipeline my serverless node code with SAM.
Please notice that the build of the node app, the build of the SAM template and deployment works perfectly if i run the same commands locally.
This is my SAM template
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Betsy Core Lambda

Resources:
  BetsyCoreLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "betsy-core-dev"
      Handler: dist/serverless.handler
      Runtime: nodejs20.x
      CodeUri: ./
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 20

This is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml
pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          name: Build
          image: node:latest
          script:
            - npm install
            - npm run build
          artifacts:
            - dist/**
            - node_modules/**
            - package.json
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Dev
          oidc: true
          deployment: Development
          image: amazon/aws-cli
          script:
            - export AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=$(pwd)/web-identity-token
            - echo $BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN > $(pwd)/web-identity-token

            - if [[ ! -f "sam-installation/dist/sam" ]]; then
                echo "SAM CLI not found. Installing...";
                yum install -y unzip;
                curl -Lo aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases/latest/download/aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip;
                unzip -q -o aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip -d sam-installation;
                ./sam-installation/install;
              fi
            - export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/sam-installation/dist/
            - sam --version

            - sam build -t template.yml
            - sam package --output-template-file packaged.yaml --s3-bucket $S3_CLOUDFORMATION_BUCKET
            - sam deploy --template-file packaged.yaml --stack-name betsy-core --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM  --no-fail-on-empty-changeset --s3-bucket $S3_CLOUDFORMATION_BUCKET

This is the error i am getting:
+ sam build -t template.yml

    SAM CLI now collects telemetry to better understand customer needs.

    You can OPT OUT and disable telemetry collection by setting the

    environment variable SAM_CLI_TELEMETRY=0 in your shell.

    Thanks for your help!

    Learn More: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-telemetry.html

Building codeuri: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build runtime: nodejs20.x architecture: x86_64 functions: BetsyCoreLambda

Build Failed

Error: NodejsNpmBuilder:Resolver - Path resolution for runtime: nodejs20.x of binary: npm was not successful

if its useful here is the tree of my project
.
├── bitbucket-pipelines.yml
├── src/
├── nest-cli.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── template.yml
├── tsconfig.build.json
└── tsconfig.json

Please help me, i really got stucked :(

Check if the node:latest you use in your yaml file is actually the same as what you have in your sam template.
I'm pretty sure that it's not, it will be 22, probably.
22 is the docker image tagged latest, so you really don't have the binary there.
Just specify node 20 instead of latest in your pipeline image.

Try to run a sam build with the parameter --use-container or -u.

If your functions depend on packages that have natively compiled
dependencies, use this option to build your function inside a
Lambda-like Docker container.

Try this command sam build -u -t template.yml.
